# Rails controller contents into separate configuration file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controllers

Does anybody know a good way to separate out a controller item into a separate file? I have the following in of my controller.

```
def admin?
    session[:password] == "password"
end
```

But I'd like to separate the "password" into a separate file so I can ignore it from a public git repo?

Is there an easy way to do this? Without storing this in a database?

Comment: I don't have much time to deeply explain why you're doing it wrong, but your approach seems *completely* wrong. first, the `admin?` should be tied to a model so you could do `user.admin?` instead of checking the sessions, then the password should NEVER be stored in the session, and finally , you should NEVER hardcode a password in a file.

Comment: you should read that : http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#session-guidelines

Comment: Thanks @pjam, I think I will look into implementing a user model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try to use `ENV` variables. first set the environment variable to a value.

`export MYAPPPASSWORD=1234`

then use this in an initializer

```
# config/initializers/my_app_password.rb
ENV['MYAPPPASSWORD'] = `printf "%s" $MYAPPPASSWORD`
```

then you can just call `ENV['MYAPPPASSWORD']`

Comment: Thanks this is useful, after reading some of the other comments, I think I'm going to implement a users model.

Answer (score 0):

Although its a bad practice to store password in session and use it in this way. But still, if you have specific reasons to do it this way then you can store in a yml file under your config directory or anywhere. I am giving the example under config directory:

in your /config/passwords.yml

```
password: your_password_text_here_without_quotes
```

and in your controller/model/anywhere load the file and get the password.

```
password = YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root}/config/passwords.yml")["password"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a global constant to deal with these settings.
Define for example a yml file in the config directory:

```
#config/password.yml
password: MyPassword
```

Use an initializer to load your settings on system start. Something like:

```
#config/initializers/load_password.rb
conf_file = File.join(Rails.root, 'config', 'password.yml')
MY_CONFIG = OpenStruct.new YAML.load_file(conf_file)
```

Access this in your whole project with:

```
MY_CONFIG.password
```

But you should not use this approach for dealing with the password in that way.
For a simple authentication look for example for this [basic authentication](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/HttpAuthentication/Basic.html)